# How to update the value of the spinner when clicking a "reset" button

Tags: java, javafx, spinner

I am trying to set the value of a spinner manually when I click a button called Reset. Is there a way to do this because I looked through the java api and I couldn't find any simple method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
spinner.getValueFactory().setValue(...);
```